# continuous backup with SyncBack Pro v6.4?

Tags: windows-7, backup

I have been unsuccessfully trying to setup continous backup with SyncBack Pro v6.4.

How can I enable real-time versioned backups of some selected folders?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: SyncBack Pro v6.4

Answer (score -1):

While I'm not 100% sure the newer version of SyncBack support the type of continuous sync you're after, you can set the schedule to run every n minutes or even n seconds (depending on the amount of data (and number of files) being synced.

You'll also have to take the connection type into account (eg. slower link = sync less often).

Hope this helps.